# Why does lint complain "Warning 446: side effect in initilizer", lint e446 for the code below?

Tags: c++, linux, lint

I need help understanding why lint complains on the code below due to the `struct` initialization.
The code runs without any issues, or at least any known issues that is

```
struct MsgKey_t {
    int type;
    int index;
    int signal;
};

typedef std::map< int, std::pair< MsgKey_t*, int* > > MyMap_t;

MyMap_t myMap;

MyMap_t::iterator subKey = myMap.find( 11 );

if ( myMap.end() == subKey )
{
    exit(-1);
}

MsgKey_t key = { subKey->second.first->type, subKey->second.first->index, subKey->second.first->signal };
```

If I change the initialization of the struct to look like:

```
MsgKey_t key;
memcpy( &key, subKey->second.first, sizeof( key ) );
```

or :

```
MsgKey_t* pKey = subKey->second.first;
MsgKey_t key = { pKey->type, pKey->index, pKey->signal };
```

lint is happy all day.

Comment: Oops missed the ; in the sample code, however in real code this is not the problem.

Comment: What is `m_My` and `MsgKey` ?

Comment: Typos m_My sgould be myMap and MsgKey should be MskKey_t

Answer (score 1):

Could lint be referring to `operator ->` in the initalization? That could possibly have side effects, depending on the implementation of the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [C++lint documentation](http://stellar.cleanscape.net/products/cpp/checks.html), this is the reason:

> Auto aggregates (arrays, structures and union) are normally
>   initialized by a collection of constant-valued expressions without
>   side-effects.  A compiler could support side-effects in which case you
>   might want to suppress this message.

It is entirely possible that these are not constant and could be subject to side effects:

`subKey->second.first->type, subKey->second.first->index, subKey->second.first->signal`

Since your `memcpy` does not technically follow a typical initialization, just moving bytes around, lint does not warn you. It will let you do it.